# Android Studio Execution failed for task ':app"dexDebug

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

sorry for my bad language; I had project in android studio and when i running it the gradle finish with this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

i use 'org.apache.http.legacy' , ZXing and Retrofit Library.
i try to re import project , delete .jar files not working
- minSDk: 11
-targetedSDK: 23

here is a screenshot from my dependencies [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6YfH.png)

Comment: Are you using multidex?

Comment: what is the meaning of multidex ?!

Comment: @Debanjan thanks for care, when i delete recylcerview dependecy the error disappear

Comment: Yes, its because multidex is not enabled. Well, I am writing as an answer the steps.

Comment: @HadeelSalah All the dependencies you are adding is perfectly working for me.So, it may be the another reason for error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable multidex in the following way.
Step 1: Write **multiDexEnabled true** inside defaultConfig in your build.gradle(app)

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
   ...
     multiDexEnabled true
    }
...
}
```

Step 2: Write

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
>   in your dependencies in the app level build.gradle

Step 3:
Build your app, Then make your application class extend **MultidexApplication**

```
public class YourApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
    }

}
```